# Rails 3 jQuery : How to alert id of td

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, coffeescript

I have a 3x3 table of td's each with id's (id='a1'...id='c3'). I'd like to be able to click on any of the 9 td's and to alert the id of that td.

Here is my Coffeescript (in the asset pipeline)

```
$(document).ready ->
$("td").click ->
    alert(#I would like to alert the id of whichever of the 9 td cell's have been clicked on)
```

Here's my index.html.erb

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td id='a1'>A1</td>
   <td id='b1'>B1</td>
   <td id='c1'>C1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td id='a2'>A2</td>
   <td id='b2'>B2</td>
   <td id='c2'>C2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td id='a3'>A3</td>
   <td id='b3'>B3</td>
   <td id='c3'>C3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm horrible at JS so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('td').click: (e)->
  alert $(@).id
```

Same in CoffeeScript

Also, storing user data with html element is very easy with data-* attributes, for example:

```
<td data-id="42"></td>
```

And getting this id is easy with jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method like follows:

```
var id = $('td').data('id');
```

Comment: That got me in the right direction, thank you!
This ended up being what worked:
    $(document).ready ->
      $("td").click ->
        alert @id

Answer (score 2):

First off, using [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) yields better performance than attaching a `click` handler to each `td`, especially if you have lots of `td`s:

```
$('table').on 'click', 'td', (event) ->
  # event.currentTarget is the td which was clicked
  alert event.currentTarget.id
```

`event.currentTarget` will be a DOM element object, and so every attribute will be available as a property of the object. The other answers referring to `$(this).id` are wrong, since `$(this)` (or `$(event.currentTarget)`) is a jQuery object, and as such attributes are available with the `attr` method: `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: I'm looking into this right now. Thanks for explaining a better approach! Always good to learn the 'best practices' or at least 'better practices'.